# Plugin "Gradle Dependencies Helper" is incompatible (supported only in intellij IDEA). but why

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

Why my android studio is keep sending message in events after updating android studio to 4.1 vesion. and not in 4.1 vesion there is also **no option to create flutter project**, what happend wrong with it, message is as bellow

**Plugin Error
Plugin "Gradle Dependencies Helper" is incompatible (supported only in intellij IDEA).**

android studion version details
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.8658069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version:1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Powered by open-source software

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is currently not supported by Android Studio. You can see the plugin here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7299-gradle-dependencies-helper/versions and clicking the most recent version shows Android Studio in 'unsupported products' list.

I had this problem too (and 2 other failings plugins), fixed it by going to

**In windows 10**

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

and deleting the .jar file(s) and folder(s) that have the same name as the failing plugin(s).

In this case: GradleDependenciesHelperPlugin-1.14.jar.